# What are the pins of a MOSFET in a TO220 package?

Tags: mosfet, to220

I have an [IRF3205](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf3205.pdf) MOSFET in a [TO-220](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TO-220) package, and I would like to know where the drain, gate and source are. I can't find this information.

Comment: It's gate, not grid. Grids are for valves.

Comment: Time to discover [datasheets](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16868/whats-this-importance-of-datasheets)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The information is available in the datasheet as you might expect (fourth hit on google).

Here is the relevant bit (page 8 of the [datasheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf3205.pdf)):

[image]

So Gate, Drain, Source, and Drain on the tab.

Comment: Sorry, I had the datasheet but didn't find the information. Even with your picture, I couldn't find the pin assignments right away. (They're on the right for those dumb like me)

Comment: I agree, it's not a good layout and I always have to look twice to find it.  Once you know though it's easy to spot.

Comment: For you datasheet writers: Best is to put the pin assignment diagram on the first page, and to make it 3D for parts like these. Sometimes I wonder if a 2D drawing is from above or below (or even front/back if the front side is not so well defined).

Comment: @starblue - *everybody* wants to have the for him relevant information on the first page. Maybe we should have datasheets with only a page 1. Size should be A\$_{-2}\$, of course.

Comment: Meh, every other semiconductor company puts the pinout on one of the first three pages, often depending on the number of packages and the pin count. I never understood why IRF and maybe a handful others put their pinouts at the end in the middle of some package drawings you normally never bother looking at.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf3205.pdf

See page 8.