# Intel Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

I have been researching on Intel microcontrollers, and cannot seem to find information on any of the controllers

1. voltage levels and reasons for such levels
2. brownout protection
3. power consumption
4. power management modes (idle, halt, wakeup)
5. over voltage protection (OVP)
6. <s>charger considerations</s>
7. <s>lowdropout.</s>

I wanted to know if there is a basic Intel microcontroller that this information is available to find, or any good websites to find this information.

Comment: All devices have datasheets. All relevant information is in the datasheets. "Reasons" for voltages are always "because we made it this way". "Dropout" is part of the power supply spec. If you specify the part numbers that you are interested in or provide other sufficient details then somebody may be able to help further.

Comment: Intel probably no longer make any device that yu would term a microcontroller. If you are interested in historical products then datasheets are probably available. Why are you asking? If it's for new products then some other brand will porobably serve you better.

Comment: Intel stopped making 8051 type microcontrollers a bunch of years ago, although there are other companies which have continued with that architecture. Intel is not really in the microcontroller business. Why are you looking for such products from them specifically? Why not Microchip, TI, Freescale, Atmel, etc?

Comment: I don't see how this is a proper question, it does not even mention which microcontroller. Author should revise or question should be closed as incomplete.

Comment: Jacob - we must know more about what you ant and why to be able to answer this well. If this is for a SERC course or project that you want to build then Intel does not currently make ANY microcontrollers and you will be better off by far finding something that is available now. If this is for historical reasons then we (the site or individuals) can help - but we need more information.

Answer (score 4):

I went to the Intel site and had a look at their microcontroller site. There's absolutely nothing there, except for a link to a part which has been discontinued since 13 years.

[Datasheets](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16868/whats-this-importance-of-datasheets/16869#16869) are crucial! They should give you an answer to all the questions you're asking: about the voltage levels (not the reasons, they don't tell you that), brownout, power consumption, etc.

You would typically compare datasheets of a number of products before you make a design choice. Watch out for parameters which are prime to your design. If you have a very low power design, the first thing to look for is power consumption, under different conditions. If your product is compact you will look at packages.

It's all in the datasheet. Now Intel doesn't seem to have datasheets, maybe because the products don't exist anymore, but whatever the reason this doesn't help you.

In that case, and that's what you always should do if the manufacturer offers you a bad service, *go to another manufacturer*. Why did you choose Intel in the first place? They haven't been a major player in the microcontroller field for many years. Today for 8-bit you would probably go to [Microchip PIC](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2551), or [Atmel AVR](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/default.aspx). For 32-bit there are many manufacturers offering ARM controllers in dozens of versions, with all kinds of features. [NXP](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers/) is a favorite of mine. Look around!

Answer (score 2):

Intel probably no longer make any device that yu would term a microcontroller.

If you are interested in historical products then datasheets are probably available.
 Why are you asking?
 If it's for new products then some other brand will probably serve you better.

---

[**Link page**](http://www.zagcom.20m.com/links/microcontroller/intel.htm) possibly of great use.

[8051 derivates - excellent](http://dipoletech.tripod.com/8051_derivatives.htm)

[Example - ATMEL  89C52 derivative of Intel product](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0313.pdf)

[809X / 839X / 879X datasheet - partial](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheets2/12/1208335_2.pdf) ollld.

[Wikipedia 8051](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51)  -  variants made by many many many people.

[8048 - as above](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-48)

[80186/80286 app note](http://www.ece.mtu.edu/faculty/btdavis/courses/ut_eecs416/80186interface.pdf) - no electrical material.

I probably have data books with these in :-)

[Possible use](http://parts.digikey.com/1/parts-kws/intel-microcontrollers)

[87C51 part datasheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Intel%20PDFs/8xC51RA,RB,RC.pdf)

[Relevant](http://www.ceibo.com/eng/linecard/intel.shtml)

Comment: Russell, you don't want to sell him into an 8048, do you? Seriously...

Comment: @stevenvh - People ask questions for many reasons. Odds are he is really after a suitable uC for a current task but he MAY be interested historically. I said "If you are interested in historical products then datasheets are probably available.
Why are you asking?" - BUT I also answered his question in part. 'A bob each way'. May even work :-).