# 2N2222 Base Current Maximum Tolerance

Tags: transistors, current

I have a 2N2222 transistor that I plan to use with an Arduino Uno. My question is how much current can this transistor handle at it's base?

Comment: Have you tried reading the datasheet?

Comment: insufficient preliminary research

Comment: Start here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/16868/2028

Comment: @ConnorWolf: not all datasheets list a maximum base current. I checked OnSemi and ST and neither seems to have this information. The question seems legimite.

Comment: @Johan.A - You can extrapolate maximum base current from the maximum collector current and beta (\$H_{FE}\$)

Comment: @ConnorWolf: ok, but that would be very much on the safe side. I've seen transistors with Ic max 1A, HFE 200 and Ib max 100 mA. A higher current than the theoretical 5 mA will be needed in saturation.

Comment: @ConnorWolf you forgot about saturation.

Comment: Who marked this as off-topic?

Comment: @ConnorWolf that's it's practical limit (more than that is just wasted/unneeded). Not it's absolute limit (more than that breaks it).

Comment: @markrages  I have started the close-voting here with a custom message "insufficient preliminary research".  In this relatively new SE setup, custom close reasons exist only in the "off-topic" category and not at the root of the selection tree.

Comment: The problem with this question isn't the base current business, but that it lacks a schematic, or at least a high level description of **how** the transistor is to be used with the microcontroller board.  Perhaps the maximum base current handling is not actually important. In many transistor applications, we don't even give this a second thought.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Fairchild PN2222 data sheet says the base-emitter saturation voltage is 2V with a collector current of 500mA and a base current of **50mA**. This is for a small duty cycle of 2% with the pulse width less than 300us.

I guess this means the base could take 50mA but how long could it take it for is a bit of a guess really.

If we look at the wattages, 50mA x 2V = 100mW and with collector-emitter saturating at 1V for Ic = 500mA we get 500mW. That's 600mW in total and pretty close to the absolute max rating of 625mW.

You could argue that if the collector current were limited to somewhat less than 500mA the overall power disippation would be less and maybe the 50mA is sustainable indefinitely.

[Multicomp's](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/296640.pdf) 2N2222 data sheet quotes min H\$_{FE}\$ of 30 at a collector current of 500mA and this implies a base current of **16.67mA**. The same data sheet also quotes **50mA** base current when specifying base-emitter saturation voltage. It also has the same caviats on duty cycle and pulse width as Fairchild.

It looks like [ON semi's](http://www.2n2222datasheet.com/pdf/on_semiconductor_2n2222_datasheet.pdf) data sheet has a nice graph on page 4 (figure 4) that gives a bit more detail.

My personal conclusion - don't run the base current continuously at more than **20mA** - this is based on gut feeling and the data I've seen.