# What does "TYP" mean in a datasheet?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, pcb-layers, pc

I am designing a PCB model of the ATmega32 using Altium Designer

I have found the word "TYP" in the dimensions of the ATmega32 in the datasheet.

What does this word refer to?

Comment: Somewhere between MIN and MAX.

Comment: See also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/277525/35022

Answer (score 3):

It means **typical**, which indicates the typical value of a dimension.

Comment: Ok..but does typical means that the dimension has no tolerance or not?

Comment: It may have tolerances according to some standards, or it may be a typical value that doesn't worth to give any tolerances. I'm not sure, but [ANSI/ASME Y1.1-1989](https://www.noao.edu/ets/Mechanical/Policies/ANSI%20Y14.24M-1989.pdf) or [ASME Y14.5M-1994](https://members.marticonet.sk/jkuba/normy/ASME_Geometry_Dimension%20and%20Tolerances_Handouts.pdf) may help.

Comment: everything has tolerances. Sometimes you can see typical, as well as minimum and/or maximum values written next to it, if you're lucky, you may even have a value distribution graph somewhere in the datasheet, it depends of course on what characteristic we're talking about and if it makes sense to give graphs for it. Physical dimensions all have tolerances, you can find them on the bottom of the datasheets, where footprints are drawn and described